# Get posts from current category?

Tags: posts, query-posts, get-posts

How can i display 5 posts from current category (exclude current post). Order by post time.

***Example:***

- To day news to reading 3 (12/11/2012 - 8:10 PM)
- To day news to reading 2 (12/11/2012 - 6:07 AM)
- To day news to reading 1 (12/11/2012 - 6:05 AM)
- Yesterday news to reading 2 (11/11/2012 - 9:10 PM)
- Yesterday news to reading 1 (11/11/2012 - 7:12 AM)

Comment: what happens in the case where the current post is one of the 5 latest posts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function filter_where_older( $where = '' ) {
    $date = get_the_time('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $where .= " AND post_date < '$date'";
    return $where;
}

function filter_where_newer( $where = '' ) {
    $date = get_the_time('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $where .= " AND post_date > '$date'";
    return $where;
}

$category = get_the_category();
if(!empty($category)) {

    $cat_id = $category[0]->term_id;

    add_filter( 'posts_where', 'filter_where_older' );
    // retrieve older posts from current post
    $query = new WP_Query( "cat=$cat_id&order=ASC&posts_per_page=5" );
    remove_filter( 'posts_where', 'filter_where_older' );

    add_filter( 'posts_where', 'filter_where_newer' );
    // retrieve newer posts from current post
    $query = new WP_Query( "cat=$cat_id&posts_per_page=5" );
    remove_filter( 'posts_where', 'filter_where_newer' );

}
```

Comment: Thanks @Mridul Aggarwal!
Older list is ok. but newer list is sorting upside down.

Comment: That was intentional, try adding `&order=ASC` in the parameter of `WP_Query`. In the answer, i added this only in one of them

Comment: filter_where_newer: $where .= " AND post_date > '$date'";
So the query will get all posts which have post_date > current post date. If we use &order=ASC it will display 5 newest posts of current category. when i change &order=DESC newer list is sorting upside down. :)

Sorry if my english is not good :D
Thanks for help @Mridul Aggarwal!

Comment: `$query->posts=array_reverse($query->posts);` should reverse the order. Try it after the newer query. Also call `$query->rewind_posts()` to reset the state